# Merge [ews], [exchangews] and [exchangewebservices]

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed, synonym-request, sponsored-tags

[ews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews) and [exchangewebservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchangewebservices) are the same and **both are sponsored**.
<del>There also is [exchangews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchangews)</del>

Can we replace [ews](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ews) with [exchangewebservices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/exchangewebservices)?

Due to sponsoring, I guess that must be escalated to SE sales?

Comment: Hmm, only 5 views; this is going to take a while...

Comment: [exchangews] (x31) looks easy to clean-up.

Comment: I nearly wrote the same request, until I saw what I was writing as a duplicate. IT looks like exchangews has been manually cleaned up.

Comment: @vcsjones we need traction on this question from a mod.

Comment: Just ran into a review audit that added `ews` to a question that already had `exchangewebservices`.  Yah, these should probably be cleaned up somehow.

Comment: I just ran into an instance of a guy adding ews to a bunch of questions that already had exchangewebservices. I approved a couple of them because they seemed legitimate - when I kept getting them, I looked closer and discovered the two tags that look pretty darn similar but aren't synonyms. So this definitely doesn't seem to have been done, and probably should. (I was about to create a meta post, but then found this one.) Meanwhile, I'm guessing we probably shouldn't approve those edits?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Just saw that too. Agreed that they should be merged/synonyms.

Comment: Looks like [tag:exchangews] is dead, but the other two still exist.

Comment: Four years later, and no action taken?

Comment: @Kayasax it hasn't been 4 years....

Comment: Oops. That s still be 5 months old

Comment: I just noticed this.  It's only 900 questions, maybe we should get busy.  I retagged ~500 questions to get rid of the dreaded serial tag.

Comment: If we end up merging these tags, we [should rename it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/25474469#25474469) to [exchange-web-services] which is easier to read.

Comment: Are we taking bets on whether this gets to 4 years old without being resolved? :P  [ews] at 1.8k is currently winning over [exchangewebservices] at 1.4k

Answer (score 4):

I was about to open a ticket to request this rename and found I had already voted on this one . . . oops.  I'm going to do some retagging today.  I suggest we just hop on it and get it done before PaulG's prediction comes true.

EDIT

Someone made the synonym!  Life is good!