# Is a question a duplicate if the duplicate has no answers?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, meta

I wrote [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277949/merge-ews-and-exchangewebservices) a few minutes ago, and couldn't help noticing that it has a [duplicate question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265235/merge-ews-exchangews-and-exchangewebservices).

However, the duplicate question does not have any answers, let alone any accepted answers. It is also a duplicate of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/268124/tag-synonym-request-ews-and-exchangewebservices).

[image]

My question: can a duplicate question be flagged as such if the 'master question' has no answers?

*I'm talking about Meta here, not the main site.*

Comment: my 2 cents: duplicate is defined (when you flag) as "has been asked before and already has an answer". So I'd say no

Comment: @Patrice Meta is different though.

Comment: @Servy true, but flagging on meta still returns that text. So that might be an interesting thing to remove?

Comment: I just voted to close as dupe and it was accepted.

Comment: @Patrice Meh, when you get to the point where you're talking about power users on meta, you don't really need to be as concerned about such things.  They tend to know what they're doing.

Comment: @Servy fair enough, but I'm of the mentality that UIs should be clear and unequivocal. I still get your point that the benefit/work ratio isn't worth it for that

Comment: @Patrice No, the text is ***turned off***: http://puu.sh/d6KEL/a966d23cf8.png

Comment: @cybermonkey, but before you actually click on the dupe flag. When I just want to flag your question, under "duplicate" I see the exact text I mentioned. Unless it's a cache issue and I carry that text over from non-meta?

Comment: @Patrice I don't see that text.

Comment: @cybermonkey could be a cache issue I guess. But as soon as I click on "flag" for a question, under "it is a duplicate" there's that tidbit. Anyway irrelevant, as it seems my 2 cents (and the UI) were wrong

Comment: @cybermonkey I guess I'm being unclear. Click on "flag". Don't choose your reason. Under each reason there's a bit of text, no? the text under the "dupe" reason is what I pointed to

Comment: @Patrice Oh, I don't know about that. The very fact that the 'duplicate question has no answers' is turned off on Meta seems to suggest that posting duplicates is *okay* as long as the 'master question' has no answers/activity for a while. It might be a big ask, but it'll be nice if someone points to *official policy from Stack Exchange* on this.

Comment: @Patrice No, I don't see that. Perhaps it is a caching issue to do with the design switchover (as the new Meta design is buggy).

Comment: @cybermonkey, is [this](http://i.imgur.com/HaLsaE7.png) the text you are missing?

Comment: @Bolu What do you mean? ***As highlighted in animuson's answer, this feature is turned off for Meta.***

Comment: @cybermonkey I mean, you should still be able to see the text, the text itself is not turned off. I think you were saying you didn't/can't see it.

Comment: @Bolu Yeah, I don't see the text *at all*, perhaps it's browser-dependent? I'm using the latest Chrome.

Comment: @AwalGarg Not funny; this is a serious question..

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Yes, it is still a duplicate. The environment here on Meta is different than on main. The most relevant thing is that questions here on Meta don't always attract answers until something has actually been done about it. You see this most frequently with bug reports and feature requests.

That **does not** mean we need to go around creating duplicates of the same thing just because the other one isn't answered, and **that is exactly why the "it must have answers" rule for duplicate closures is turned off here on Meta** - because that rule simply is not useful here.

Comment: `That does not mean we need to go around creating duplicates of the same thing just because the other one isn't answered`, so surely the 'it must have answers' rule should be turned *on* here on Meta?

Comment: Why would we do that?

Comment: If it was turned on, surely it would be *enforcing* the rule of 'don't create duplicates just because the other has no answers'. The fact it is turned off here suggests something different.

Comment: You seem to be thinking backwards. On normal sites, there is a rule in the code that, when closing as a duplicate, the target question has to have an answer in order for it to work. That rule is ignored/off on Meta sites. Turning that on would encourage the *opposite* - people would ask more duplicates because they can't be closed as duplicates of those unanswered questions.

Comment: @cybermonkey consider the question "there's a bug when rendering the front page".  It doesn't have an answer because it isn't answerable yet. And then someone else comes to meta and asks about the same bug... and another person and another person.  Being able to close these as dups of the unanswered original bug is a Very Good Thing.  Requiring there to be an uprooted answer in the target question would make it harder to point people to the right spot for where an answer is likely to appear.

Comment: @animuson: I never heard of that rule, and I must admit I do not understand why it would be relevant even outside Meta. Whether a question has an answer or not does not change whether it's the same question. Rather than cluttering the system with another unanswered question I would rather allow closing as duplicates and bump the question identified as "master" as a new question would be so it gains visibility again.

Comment: @MatthieuM. The question I posted was to specifically gain visibility of the 'master question'.

Comment: @MatthieuM. this rule was introduced in Feb '13, see [Changes to “close as duplicate” (part deux)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) at MSE: _"That's because the proof is in the answers..."_ Not that I am happy with it, but I somehow got used to it, partially because they relaxed another part of the issue: _' No argument about how exact an "exact duplicate" needs to be...'_

Comment: @gnat: Thanks for the heads up. Indeed the relaxation is a goodie.

Comment: @MatthieuM. given that you also like that relaxation, you might be interested in another MSE discussion that drilled deeper into this aspect of a new rule: [Does the new guidance on duplicate questions suggest closing a question as duplicate, if the original answers the OP's question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/217401/165773) "...seems to suggest that, if some other question in the system answers the OP's question, then the OP's question can be closed as a duplicate on that basis (even if the question itself is not necessarily duplicated)..."

Comment: @gnat: I am on the fence with this rule. On the one hand repeating answers seems useless, on the other pointing to a completely different question might throw the reader off ("that's not what I am asking about!!"). I would really like have a way to "share" an answer between questions, but it is not obvious how best to...

Comment: @MatthieuM. that's right, I saw askers confused by this, despite getting their answer "over there". I also saw this sometimes causing some... extra friction so to speak. From what I saw, the _grease_ to make it smoother is a comment or answer explaining connection to the dupe target and how answer(s) over there really address specific asker's situation

Comment: @gnat If there is an old unanswered Meta question, how can we 'bump' it? I know that moderators are able to add a [tag:featured] tag, but I have no idea if flagging a question for moderator attention just to get it featured is the right thing to do (***probably not***).

Comment: @cybermonkey at per-site metas, there's no easy way, see [How to get attention to a post on a child meta site](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/188814/165773) and questions linked to it. Do I hate it? you bet

Comment: @gnat On the main sites it is possible to put a bounty on a question in order to get attention, but not on Meta. There's no easy way as you said.

Comment: Is the reason you don't answer e.g., bug-report questions to be able to spot not-yet-addressed reports? I think it would be much more intuitive (for those unfamiliar with the currently adopted approach) to add a short placeholder answer to the "master-question": _Thanks for spotting this! We are considering/working on this and we will put any updates here._